# Vue3 redirect to another page after the file has been downloaded

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, router

The user receives a link from the server to download the file, then the function to download the file is started, after downloading the file the user should be taken to the main page.

```
<script setup lang="ts">

const goToMain = (time: number) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    router.push({
      name: ERouteName.PAGE_HOME
    })
  }, time)
}

try {
  const { query } = router.currentRoute.value
  const { url } = await clientStore.uploadAppealFile(query.file_id as string)

  if (url) {
    const link = document.createElement('a')
    link.href = url
    link.click()
    goToMain(3000)
  }
} catch (error) {
  goToMain(0)
}
</script>
```

Now I switch to the main page by timer, but I would like the goToMain() function to trigger after the end of file loading.

Comment: You may need XHR

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `await` will work unless it's in an `async` function. Try this.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onBeforeMount} from 'vue'

onBeforeMount( async() => {
try {
  const { query } = router.currentRoute.value
  const { url } = await clientStore.uploadAppealFile(query.file_id as string)

  if (url) {
    const link = document.createElement('a')
    link.href = url
    link.click()
    
  }
} catch (error) {
  .....
}
})
</script>
```